# Autopep8 выдаёт ошибку при попытке форматирования в Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

В *Visual Studio Code* установлены следующие расширения для работы с форматированием в  Python:

- [autopep8](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.autopep8)
- [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

Установил **autopep8** в качестве formatter'а по умолчанию:

`"editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"`

При попытке выполнить форматирование документа (Format Document) получаю следующую ошибку:

```
  File "c:\Users\Lotrein\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.autopep8-2023.4.0\bundled\tool\lsp_server.py", line 421, in _run_tool_on_document
    result = utils.run_module(
  File "c:\Users\Lotrein\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.autopep8-2023.4.0\bundled\tool\lsp_utils.py", line 149, in run_module
    return _run_module(module, argv, use_stdin, source)
  File "c:\Users\Lotrein\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.autopep8-2023.4.0\bundled\tool\lsp_utils.py", line 132, in _run_module
    runpy.run_module(module, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\Lotrein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 227, in run_module
    return _run_code(code, {}, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "c:\Users\Lotrein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Lotrein\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.autopep8-2023.4.0\bundled\libs\autopep8.py", line 414, in <module>
    del pycodestyle._checks['logical_line'][pycodestyle.continued_indentation]
KeyError: <function continued_indentation at 0x0000029E87257A30>
```

При этом, если я форматирую файл с использованием самого *расширения* "Python", то оно выполняется успешно, но я не уверен, что оно учитывает *pep8*.

Пробовал переустанавливать расширения, перезапускать Python, выполнять "autopep8: Restart Server" (что бы это ни значило) - пока ничего из этого не помогло.

Что ещё можно было бы здесь попробовать, чтобы решить проблему?